# Structure data in app engine ndb and speed up query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I am looking for some help as to the best way to structure data in app engine ndb using python, process it and query it later. I want to store temperature data at hourly intervals for different geographical regions.

I can think of two entity options but there maybe something much better. The first would be to store the hourly temperature in individual properties:

```
class TempData(ndb.Model):
    region = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateProperty()
    00:00 = ndb.FloatProperty()
    01:00 = ndb.FloatProperty()
    ...
    23:00 = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

Or I could store the data

```
class TempData(ndb.Model):
    region = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateProperty()
    time = ndb.TimeProperty()
    temp = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

(it might be better to store date and time as one property?)

I want to be able to query the datastore to calculate the Total, Max, Min, and average temperature for any given date range. In the first option I could potentially create 4 more properties to effectively pre-process and store the Total, Max etc for each day so if I wanted to query the total temperature for a year I would only have to sum 365 values as opposed to 8760? I'm not sure how I would do this in the second option?

I am relatively new to app engine and datastore and I think I am still thinking in terms of relationship db's so any help would really be appreciated. Later on it might be necessary to store data in different time zones.

Thanks

Paul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally, I'd go with a variant of the first approach:

```
class TempData(ndb.Model):
    region = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateProperty()
    temp = ndb.FloatProperty(repeated=True)
```

using the `temp` list to store temperatures by hour in order as you learn about them. I don't think the preprocessing per-date will add anything much: to compute whatever for a year, you'd still need to fetch 365 entities, and the delay for that will swamp the tiny amount of time required to sum up a few thousand numbers anyway.

In general, preprocessing is useful if you want to handily query by the new fields you create by such processing (e.g rapidly answer the question "which dates in locale X had average temperatures greater than 20 Celsius"). That does not seem to be your use case.

If anything, if it's common for you to have to compute many-month values, preprocessing to aggregate things per-month (into simpler `TempDataMonth` entities) may be more useful. Or, any other several-days period you find useful, of course (weeks, ten-day-groups, whatever). Those could be computed in a background task periodically checking which such periods have become complete since the last check. But, this is a bit beyond your question, so I'm not getting into fine-grained details.

The general idea is that minimizing the number of entities to fetch tends to be the single most important optimization; other optimizations are of course also possible, but, they tend to play second fiddle to that:-).

Comment: Thanks Alex, that makes sense. What would happen if there was a missing value, would I just be able to store a blank value to query by exception later? Would there be a way to query the repeated property to get the max temp at 12:00pm for example?

Comment: @Ron, you could store a `float('NaN')` as a place-holder for missing data. Of course, if you do arithmetic on a `NaN`, in Python it propagates, so if you want best-effort max or average for a date with missing data you'll have to filter the `NaN`s out yourseif in your Python code.  As for "max temp at 12:00` you'll need to first fetch all the relevant entities then use a Python loop to determine the result. Defining exactly which queries you'll use often needing a fast response is *crucial* in using any NoSQL database.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I'll give it a go